# Помогите в работе с вложенными циклами!

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть код:

```
for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){ // основной цикл


for($z=0;$z<10;$z++) { //вложенный цикл
if($z==0) { $zapros.=' return {'; }
$zapros .=' "rst'.$z.'":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"'.$friendsik->response->items[$k].'", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"})';
if($z!=9) { $zapros .=','; }
else { $zapros.='};'; $ho=1; }
$k=$k+1;
}

$f = fopen("bot.txt", "a+");
fwrite($f,$zapros. "         " );
fclose($f);

}
return 0; // Пофиг что выводить
}
```

В данном фрагменте кода я создаю execute запрос к серверу вк.
Дело в том что вложенный цикл должен создавать тело execute запроса а именно переменную code (для тех кто шарит в vk api). Собственно проблема в том что при первой итерации основного цикла, вложенный цикл создаёт переменную zapros как надо, а именно в текстовый документ записываветься вот это:

```
 return { "rst0":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"232472393", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst1":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"335121474", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst2":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"149082318", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst3":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"137529581", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst4":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"139572580", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst5":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"223138809", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst6":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"273106404", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst7":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"211408588", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst8":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"599894772", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst9":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"370411016", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"})};
```

НО, при второй итерации основного цикла  вложенный цикл выполняеться 2 раза, тоесть переменная zapros
становиться равной:

```
return { "rst0":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"232472393", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst1":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"335121474", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst2":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"149082318", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst3":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"137529581", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst4":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"139572580", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst5":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"223138809", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst6":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"273106404", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst7":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"211408588", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst8":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"599894772", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst9":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"370411016", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"})}; return { "rst0":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"570372147", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst1":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"232985818", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst2":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"439280822", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst3":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"324641024", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst4":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"375950180", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst5":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"313848521", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst6":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"307850071", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst7":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"156115157", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst8":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"146257695", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"}), "rst9":API.photos.getAll({
"owner_id":"201226959", 
"extended":"1",
"no_service_albums":"0",
"count":"30",
"photo_sizes":"1",
"skip_hidden":"0",
"v":"5.50"})};
```

ПРИ третей итерации цикла вложенный цикл повторяется три раза, и я не могу понять почему это просходит и как это исправить, если по идеи внутренний цикл должен повторяться всего один раз. Помогите!!!!!!!

Comment: Проверьте местоположение вашего return - он должен стоять там, где необходимо ВЫЙТИ ИЗ ЦИКЛОВ. Так же советую посмотреть как работает в циклах return(в какой нибудь песочнице).

Comment: Не вкладывайте в основной=)Или пропускайте на следующих итерациях

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, вы сами добавляете в переменную `$zapros` новое содержимое, т.к. используете конкатенацию: `$zapros.=' return {';` вместо `$zapros=' return {';`

Во вторых, вы пишете в файл в режиме **a+**, т.е. дозаписываете в файл новое содержимое переменной `$zapros`.

Решайте сами, что из этого лишнее.

---

Также, никто так не формирует json, это попросту неудобно.
Собирайте данные в массив, а потом вызывайте `json_encode`.
Опредённые сложности создаёт вызов js функции, но тем не менее.
Например, так:

```
$queries = [];
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $json = json_encode($row);
    $queries[] = "\"{$key}\": API.photos.getAll({$json})";
}
$json_entries = implode(",\n\t", $queries);
$zapros = "return {\n\t{$json_entries}\n};\n";
```